# Laravel Link data queries and pagination

Tags: php, laravel

How can I combine 3 requests into one to process it through "foreach" and display it with pagination?

```
$data['diamond_ads'] = AdModel::where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 1)->orderByDesc('date_added')->get();
$data['vip_ads'] = AdModel::where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0)->where('ad_vip', '=', 1)->orderByDesc('date_added')->get();
$data['default_ads'] = AdModel::where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0)->where('ad_vip', '=', 0)->orderByDesc('date_added')->get();
```

Comment: why do you separate if then will be combined?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this query , give it a try

```
AdModel::where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)
        ->where(function($query){
            $query->where('ad_diamond', '=', 1);
            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('ad_vip', '=', 1);
                $query->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0);
            });
            $query->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('ad_vip', '=', 0);
                $query->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0);
            });
        })->orderByDesc('date_added')->paginate();
```

Comment: Your code example outputs 1 diamond ad on the first page. And another diamond ad on the second page. And so on.

Comment: are you passing argument to paginate ? paginate(1) @neowaring

Answer (score 0):

As you use three separate queries and now you want to combine them, you can use all your queries in on query and handle that with `orWhere` in laravel like this:

```
AdModel::where(function (Builder $query){
        $query->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 1);
      })->orWhere(function(Builder $query){
        $query->where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0)->where('ad_vip', '=', 1)
      })->orWhere(function(Builder $query){
        $query->where('status', 1)->where('moderation','=', 0)->where('category_id', '=', $this_category_id)->where('ad_diamond', '=', 0)->where('ad_vip', '=', 0)
      })->orderByDesc('date_added')->paginate();
```

Comment: Your code example outputs 1 diamond ad on the first page. And another diamond ad on the second page. And so on.